# Orgmode table error - shrunk field?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, error-handling

I'm very new to Emacs and Org mode, so I'm basically fumbling around. I'm getting an alarm bell ding whenever I type in an table in an `*.org` file.  A message says `"invalid function: org-table-with-shrunk-field"` in the echo area.

I get the error even with a simple example such as the following:

```
| A | B | C |
| a
```

When I type "a", I get the alarm.

I'm using Emacs 26.1 and Org mode version 9.2.

Here is the Debugger info:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function org-table-with-shrunk-field)
  org-table-with-shrunk-field(nil)
  org-self-insert-command(1)
  funcall-interactively(org-self-insert-command 1)
  call-interactively(org-self-insert-command nil nil)
  command-execute(org-self-insert-command)
```

Any idea what I can do about this?

I am using org-version 9.1.9 when I use `-Q` and 9.2 when I start it up as usual.

Also, when I commented out the following lines from my init file, I did not get the error. This isn't a solution, however, as I need a couple packages.

`(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") 
             ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")))
(package-initialize)`

Comment: Which Emacs and Org version do you use?

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t`, to see why/where/when Emacs tries to invoke this invalid function.

Comment: To speed up the troubleshooting, please update you question with a simple example , e.g. `|  |`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since you are a beginner I will elaborate on [Drew's comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46923/orgmode-table-error-shrunk-field#comment72252_46923). You can use the Graphical User Interface to set `debug-on-error` to `t`: Just open the `Options` menu and check the `Enter Debugger on Error` menu item there. We hope that when the error happens a new window with a stacktrace will open. Copy that stacktrace and paste it into your question. That will help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful feedback. I've edited the post with more information.

Comment: I’m wondering if it’s throwing error because the syntax for columns hasn’t defined yet. Did you try adding the extra pipes to row before adding `a`?

Comment: @Melioratus Even when the pipes are added, it gives me the error. Basically I get the alarm when I input cell data after the first row.

Comment: The next generic step is to check emacs base installation by starting emacs like this  `emacs -Q`. After emacs starts up, open org file & try inserting row in table. If problem is resolved, the issue is caused by a new package or config. My guess is your issue will go away with `-Q`. If so, do `M-x org-version` when using `-Q` and without `-Q`. BTW `M` is shorthand `Meta` key. To do this press either `Alt` key or `Esc` key and `x` at same time then type `org-version` and press `return` or `enter` key. The org-mode version will be displayed in minibuffer. Please reply with results.

Comment: @Melioratus You're right. No problem whatsoever with tables when I use `-Q`. I'm apparently using org-version 9.1.9 with `-Q` and 9.2 without.

Comment: Great! So the issue might be a corrupted 9.2 install. Using 9.2, 1) open your org file. 2) Confirm table still broken by inserting content. 3) Reload Org uncompiled by doing these key chords `C-u` `C-c` `C-x` then type `!` and press `return` or `enter`.  BTW `C` -s shorthand for `Ctrl` or `control` key, so `C-u` would be pressing `Crtl` key and letter `u` at same time. 
After buffer reloads, 4) Test if table is still broken. Please reply with results.

Comment: @Melioratus That seemed to fix the table error. However, when I quit and then restarted Emacs, and loaded an org file  and made another table, the error was still there. It think it has something to do with `org-plus-contrib`. When I delete that package, the error goes away completely...but I need the package in order to use `ox-extra`.

Comment: From your results the issue appears to be corrupted or out of date byte compiled files for org 9.2. To fix you need to 1) delete the all `.elc` files in the org 9.2 directory. 2) byte compile the all the `.el` files and restart emacs and test if issue is resolved. My guess is it will be. Please reply with results and/or questions.

Comment: @Melioratus I gave that a shot. Now, when I enter data into a table cell, I get the message `org-self-insert-command: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-table--shrunk-field`. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Making progress! My guess is that this new error is most likely due to having 2 versions of org-mode installed. Uninstall version 9.1.9 and restart emacs then test for table issue. Please reply with results.

Comment: @Melioratus Somewhere between the uninstall/reinstall attempts I got it to work! Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Congratulations! It was my pleasure! You should write a quick summary of the steps you did and answer your own question. Your answer could be as simple as `resolved issue by uninstalling all versions of org-mode from emacs and reinstalling 9.2`. The answer will save the next person all the troubleshooting time. Thanks for asking your question!

Comment: I have the same question when I input Chinese character in the form for a while, and then re-installed the org-plus-contrib package where the error is located. I found an error, about
Arduino-mode, then installed **arduino-mode**, restart emacs, then it seems ok

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same `(invalid-function org-table-with-shrunk-field)` issue and resolved it with the following process, gleaned from the comments:

1. confirm the source of the issue with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-version`, which said: "Org mode version 9.2 (9.2-elpa @ /path/to/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20181230/)"
2. attempt to fix corrupted or out-of-date byte-compiled org 9.2 files by deleting all .elc files in the org 9.2 directory named in step 1, then <kbd>M-x</kbd> `byte-recompile-directory` that dir
3. Re-test showed the issue was fixed, but as hinted by a comment above, an Emacs restart and re-test showed that the problem was back!
4. Assuming a corrupted org 9.2 install as described in the comments, I reloaded all Org lisp files with <kbd>C-u C-c C-x !</kbd> (which calls `org-reload`)
5. A re-test including an Emacs restart confirmed the issue was fixed

Comment: You need to prefix `byte-recompile-directory` by `M-0` because it **does not** compile if the `.elc` file does not exist.

Comment: does anybody knows what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

Please see here: https://orgmode.org/Changes.html#orgeeff4d2

In Org 9.2, you'll need to add `shrink` to the startup option line:

`#+STARTUP: align shrink`

The shrinking behaviour has changed from the previous version of Org. Now the columns will expand automatically as soon as you start editing an field. Also the shortcut for expanding or shrinking columns has changed to `C-c TAB`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but unfortunately the error persists.